# How to create a dictionary for certain string in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following column containing subject ID's and would like to match it with the scoring column to the right of it by taking the sum of that ID's score and putting it in a dictionary with the ID and score as key/value.  Here are the two columns:

```
subject   Score
phchp005  1
phchp005  0
phchp006
phchp006
phchp006  0 
phchp006  0
phchp006  0
phchp006  0 
phchp006  1
phchp006  1
phchp006  1
phchp008
```

So the output would be a dictionary like this:

```
{phchp005: 1, phchp006: 3, phchp008: 0}
```

There are NaN Values as well that I will just fill with 0's.
Thanks.

Comment: I assume that `phchp006` should be 3? Also those are empty strings or NaNs in the Score column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via `groupby()`:

```
out=df.groupby('subject')['Score'].sum().astype(int).to_dict()
```

output of `out`:

```
{'phchp005': 1, 'phchp006': 3, 'phchp008': 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate the dataframe test data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "subject": 2 * ["phchp005"] + 9 * ["phchp006"] + 1 * ["phchp008"],
        "Score": [1] + 7 * [0] + 3 * [1] + [0],
    }
)
```

Use Groupby:

```
df.groupby("subject").sum().to_dict()["Score"]
```

Output:

```
{'phchp005': 1, 'phchp006': 3, 'phchp008': 0}
```